# Android adapter OnChangedLisistener?

Tags: android, listview, callback, listener, adapter

I am asking if there is a way to have a listener for adapter on changed, I deed something like

```
adapter.setOnChangedLisistener(new OnChangedLisistener() {

public void onChanged() {
// my code here
}

});
```

So that I can be notified when adapter is modified

Answer (score 2):

```
public class YourAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<YourClassName> {// for example
    // constructor, getView and other methods goes here

    // you need to create OnChangedLisistener interface

    public interface OnChangedLisistener {
        public void onChanged();

    }

    private OnChangedLisistener changeListener=null;

    public void setOnChangedLisistener(OnChangedLisistener changeListener){
        this.changeListener=changeListener;
    }


    @Override
    public void notifyDataSetChanged() {
        super.notifyDataSetChanged();
        if(changeListener!=null){
            changeListener.onChanged();
        }
    }

}
```

> initialize and set listener to adapter

```
    yourAdapter.setOnChangedLisistener(new OnChangedLisistener(){
        @Override
        public void onChanged(){
            //your code here
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to extend the `Adapter` class and override `notifyDataSetChanged()` method:

```
@Override
public void notifyDataSetChanged() {
    super.notifyDataSetChanged();
    // Your code
}
```